# javascript how to detect div element height is smaller than screen height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just gonna detect the window object has a vertical scroll bar by overflowing and the child element of the window.

```
 const hasYScroll = typeof window.innerHeight === "number" && window.innerHeight > wrappedElement.clientHeight
```

I tried this already and is there any better solution for that?

Regards.

Comment: Please share your code here. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Did you just... commented on your own question asking for more code? You can just update it

Comment: Sorry, I just wanna know how can I detect if the vertical scroll appeared. 
Even I try it with my code, it was not working properly on react.js.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where is this code? You must put it on `ComponentDidMount/Update` and on `window.onResize`. My guess is, on pageload, its not rendering and hence it might be failing

Comment: Yeap, Rajesh you are right.
I am doing that inside of useEffect hook function.